# Отследить первый вход в приложение Flutter

Tags: flutter

Интересуют методы, как можно отследить первый вход юзера в приложение для показа гайд-баннера. Возможно ли это воссоздать без баз данных? Нужно ли создавать какие-то внутренние каунтеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Возможно ли это воссоздать без баз данных?

Можно, использовать [Shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), это обертка над NSUserDefaults (в iOS) и SharedPreferences (в Android). Пример:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); // Хранилище 
  bool banner = (prefs.getBool('banner') ?? true); // Получаем значение, если пустое ставим true

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: (banner) ? bannerOne(prefs) : bannerTwo(), // Проверка, в первый раз будет bannerOne, в последующие разы будет bannerTwo
  ));
}

Widget bannerOne(SharedPreferences prefs) {
  prefs.setBool('banner', false); // Меняем значение на false
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Text('Banner One'),
    ),
  );
}

Widget bannerTwo() {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Text('Banner Two'),
    ),
  );
}
```

> Нужно ли создавать какие-то внутренние каунтеры?

После перезапуска приложения ваши внутренние каунтеры сбросяться до дефолтных (которые были при инициализации).

*Ещё можно использовать БД, так как, в любом случае понадобится в дальнейшем.*